# Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react"

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to include a React component in my project. When I run this code, I get the following:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "react". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

HTML file

```
<noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
                <div id="lock-plate" style="display: none">
                    <div id="root" class="main"></div>                    
                </div>

<script src="/js/game.js" type="module"></script>
```

game.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CombinationLock from "combination-lock-react";

...

   // this is for the React module that I can't get working
    function App() {
        return /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement("div", {
          className: "app"
        }, /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(CombinationLock, {
          combination: "43920",
          height: 60,
          onMatch: () => {
            console.log("Unlock!");
          },
          openText: "Unlocked!"
        }));
      }
    // this is for the React loading for the combination lock
    const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
    ReactDOM.render( /*#__PURE__*/React.createElement(App, null), rootElement);
```

I read that perhaps the React imports are not needed, but removing them produces an error that ReactDOM isn't defined.

My package.json has "type":"module" included. My react module files appear to be in the correct folders (i.e., I didn't touch them after npm installing them).

Side note: The javascript code was originally written in JSX, but I used Babel REPL to translate it back to pure javascript since my code was not recognizing the JSX. Not sure if that has anything to do with this, but it doesn't seem to affect this issue.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

EDIT: package.json

```
{
  "name": "express-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "author": "Overlord",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@adminjs/express": "^4.1.0",
    "@adminjs/mongoose": "^2.0.2",
    "adminjs": "^5.6.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^3.1.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "combination-lock-react": "^1.0.3",
    "ejs": "^3.1.6",
    "express": "^4.17.3",
    "express-formidable": "^1.2.0",
    "express-pjax": "^0.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "mongo": "^0.1.0",
    "mongodb": "^4.4.1",
    "mongoose": "^6.2.3",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.19",
    "pjax": "^0.2.8",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-draggable": "^4.4.5",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "tslib": "^2.4.0",
    "yarn": "^1.22.17"
  },
  "type": "module",
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Can you tell us about your project setup? Did you for example use create-react-app to create the app or something else? What is your tooling and your package.json please.

Comment: With proper tooling you won't need `import React from "react"` for JSX code to work, but you still need the import to `react-dom` and also some functions from React like `import {useState} from "react"`

Comment: I basically found this combination lock code and decided I wanted to use it, without knowing anything about React :). https://www.npmjs.com/package/combination-lock-react.

Comment: So I'm sure I haven't properly tooled my project overall. I'll edit to add my package.json...

Comment: Why do you have `react-dom` 18.2 but `react` 16.14?!!!!

Comment: Also, how are you starting the frontend if you're `node server.js` instead of `react-scripts start`? Seems like you're doing server-side rendering, so may I suggest you use NextJS instead of doing it by hand?

Comment: Not sure on the different versions, I simply installed the npms from both a couple of days ago. I can look to re-install them. I'm not familiar with NextJS but will take a look, thanks!

Comment: `import React from 'react'` is required in React version < 17. That's why you get an error of `my code was not recognizing the JSX`